# How to read OpenCV documentation codes or equations

Tags: opencv, coding-style

I need help in reading OpenCV documentation:
Can you tell me how to read these types of codes given below? means what these `\` means?
How I can convert it to read able form like

```
g(i,j)=alpha.f(i,j)+beta
```

or something like this for

```
\[g(x) = \alpha f(x) + \beta\]
```

Some examples I am unable to read or understand:

```
\[g(i,j) = \alpha \cdot f(i,j) + \beta\] 
\((i_0,...,i_{M.dims-1})\), where \(0\leq i_k<M.size[k]\), is computed as:

\[addr(M_{i_0,...,i_{M.dims-1}}) = M.data + M.step[0]*i_0 + M.step[1]*i_1 + ... + M.step[M.dims-1]*i_{M.dims-1}\]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply *latex* markup to display math equations. See [here](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/htmlequations.php) for example.

> What do they mean?

---

**Multiplication and addition with a constant**

```
\[g(x) = \alpha f(x) + \beta\] 
\[g(i,j) = \alpha \cdot f(i,j) + \beta\]
```

usually for [changing the contrast and brightness of an image](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html):

[image]

[image]

---

**Data layout inside memory**

```
\((i_0,...,i_{M.dims-1})\), where \(0\leq i_k<M.size[k]\), is computed as:
\[addr(M_{i_0,...,i_{M.dims-1}}) = M.data + M.step[0]*i_0 + M.step[1]*i_1 + ... + M.step[M.dims-1]*i_{M.dims-1}\]
```

This is how data are stored inside a [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#mat):

The data layout of the array [image] is defined by the array `M.step[]`, so that the address of element [image], where [image] is computed as:

[image]

In case of a 2-dimensional array, the above formula is reduced to:

[image]